# OneDrive API giving error when processing large uploads

Tags: onedrive

When processing a large amount of data uploads using the OneDrive API I see the following error returned:

"The request wasn't made because the same type of request was repeated too many times. Wait 7 seconds and try again."

This occurs each time when doing volume based uploads.

Has any one come across this or a workaround for this ?

Comment: It appears you are probably hitting some rate limits and being throttled, so the only workaround would be waiting

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what "volume based uploads" means? How many files are you uploading, how big are the files, etc?